# Read csv file from prolog and change to facts/clause

Tags: csv, predicate, swi-prolog, fact, prolog-assert

I use `csv_read_file` to read a csv file, which is:

csv file:

```
"nsubj(love-1, carol-2)"
"nsubj(like-3, carol-2)"
```

code:

```
csv_read_file('test.csv',L)
```

I got things like:

```
L = [row('nsubj(love-1, carol-2)'), row('nsubj(like-3, carol-2)')]
```

But what I need is

```
nsubj(love-1, carol-2) and nsubj(like-3, carol-2)
```

which are predicates actually.

How can I get rid of the `row` thing? I think after that I just need to do `assert()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK..I got it myself.
It is actually quite easy but I'm new to Prolog so it took me time to figure it out.
Since Prolog can recognise the pattern, so I just make the pattern explicitly as follows:

`Rows = [Head|Tail],
Head = row(Element,_,_,_,_,_,_,_),
List = [Element|Temp]
...`

The Element here is exactly what I want.